loop or a recursive method cant get the data
I have this data in one table and I am trying to do a loop or a recursive method. I need to get the result base on using the meeting id. If I am using meetingid 1 it would return 2,3. If I do meetingid 2 i would get 1,3 and if I do 3 I would get 1,2. I have this method but I need to call in many time and I wanted to know if there is a better way.
I believe I need linq to traverses the parent/prior meeting chain and one that traverses the child/continuation meeting chain.
MeetingId       ContinuedMeetingId
----------      -------------
1               2
2               3
3               null

EF / Linq:
 var y = (from m in Meetings
          where m.MeetingId == MeetingId
          select new
          {
              ContinuedMeetingsId = db.Meetings
                 .Where(s => s.MeetingId == m.MeetingId)
                 .Select(s => s.ContinuedMeetingId).FirstOrDefault()
          }).FirstOrDefault();


So what exactly is the rule here? Select the MeetingId you did not request? You need to elaborate a bit further about what you want to do.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain I think they want a method like GetRelatedMeetings(meetingId).

And why are you retriving the meeting twice? Once from the property Meetings,  and once from db.Meetings? In other words: m already is the Meeting, no need to query it again from db.Meetings.

This can be done in SQL using two recursive CTEs - one that traverses the parent/prior meeting chain and one that traverses the child/continuation meeting chain. (The original meeting is excluded form both lists.) It is then just a matter of performing a UNION ALL and (if desired) a STRING_AGG() to build the final comma-separated list.
This logic can be wrapped up in a user-defined function which can then be added to the Entity Framework model and called from your application.
CREATE FUNCTION GetRelatedMeetings (@MeetingId INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @RelatedMeetings VARCHAR(MAX);
  
    WITH PriorMeetings AS (
        SELECT M.MeetingId
        FROM Meetings M
        WHERE M.ContinuedMeetingId = @MeetingId
        UNION ALL
        SELECT M.MeetingId
        FROM PriorMeetings PM
        JOIN Meetings M
            ON M.ContinuedMeetingId = PM.MeetingId
    ),
    ContinuedMeetings AS (
        SELECT M.ContinuedMeetingId AS MeetingId
        FROM Meetings M
        WHERE M.MeetingId = @MeetingId
        UNION ALL
        SELECT M.ContinuedMeetingId AS MeetingId
        FROM ContinuedMeetings CM
        JOIN Meetings M
            ON M.MeetingId = CM.MeetingId
    ),
    RelatedMeetings AS (
        SELECT PM.MeetingId
        FROM PriorMeetings PM
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CM.MeetingId
        FROM ContinuedMeetings CM
    )
    SELECT @RelatedMeetings =
        STRING_AGG(RM.MeetingId, ',')
            WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY RM.MeetingId)
    FROM RelatedMeetings RM;

    RETURN @RelatedMeetings
END

The above logic assumes that the meeting chain is linear with a 1-to-1 parent/child relationship. If the meeting relationships can be many-to-many, the graph traversal would be much more involved.
Although similar logic could be implemented in C#, I do not know of a way to write an equivalent recursive LINQ statement that would map to a single SQL query execution. A native LINQ implementation would likely loop and execute multiple queries. (I believe there are some add-ons that provide limited CTE support, but I do not know if they support recursion or would be adapted to this solution. That would require some more investigation.)
Results (with some extra test data):



MeetingId
RelatedMeetings




1
2,3


2
1,3


3
1,2


4
5,6,7


5
4,6,7


6
4,5,7


7
4,5,6


8
null



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore supports recursive CTE and these three can be expressed via LINQ.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv - Thank you for the link. I have no experience with that feature, but I  made an attempt at translating the SQL to the equivalent LINQ and have posted it as a separate community answer. You (and anyone else reading this) are invited to review and update as needed.

Honestly I am still not sure what you want to do. and you just edited your question by copying and pasting some keywords from the first answer you received.
So I just assume the previous answer is more or less in line with what you are looking for.
Also your var y = (from m in Meetings where m.MeetingId == MeetingId select new{}).FirstOrDefault() can be simplified by using Meetings.FirstOrDefault(m => m.MeetingId == MeetingId).
To write a while loop or recursive method in Csharp, you can try below code:
var meetings = new List<Meeting>
{
    new Meeting {MeetingId = "1", ContinuedMeetingId = "2"},
    new Meeting {MeetingId = "2", ContinuedMeetingId = "3"},
    new Meeting {MeetingId = "3", ContinuedMeetingId = null}
};

var selectedMeetingId = "1";
var nextMeetingIds = new List<string>();
var priorMeetingIds = new List<string>();
var nextMeeting = meetings.FirstOrDefault(m => m.MeetingId == selectedMeetingId);
var priorMeeting = meetings.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ContinuedMeetingId == selectedMeetingId);
while (true)
{
    if (nextMeeting == null && priorMeeting == null)
    {
        break;
    }

    if (nextMeeting != null)
    {
        var nextMeetingId = nextMeeting.ContinuedMeetingId;
        nextMeetingIds.Add(nextMeetingId);
        nextMeeting = meetings.FirstOrDefault(m => m.MeetingId == nextMeetingId);
    }

    if (priorMeeting != null)
    {
        var priorMeetingId = priorMeeting.MeetingId;
        priorMeetingIds.Add(priorMeetingId);
        priorMeeting = meetings.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ContinuedMeetingId == priorMeetingId);
    }
}


Draft, community answer
The following is a possible LINQ implementation of the earlier SQL recursive CTE answer that uses the LINQ To DB - Common Table Expression (CTE) capability.
This initial post is a draft translation of the SQL to C# LINQ based on the documentation, but it has not been tested and may need corrections. I have no experience with this, so it may need fixes or other improvements. Please feel free to edit and improve this answer as you see fit. If you can verify this as a working solution, these comments may be edited or removed as appropriate.
using LinqToDB.Configuration;
using LinqToDB.Data;

class RelatedMeetingsCTE
{
    public int MeetingId;
}

...

public string GetRelatedMeetings(int meetingId)
{
    using (var db = ...)
    {
        var priorMeetingsCte = db.GetCte<RelatedMeetingsCTE>(PriorMeetings =>
        {
            return
                (
                    from m in db.Meetings 
                    where m.ContinuedMeetingId == meetingId
                    select new RelatedMeetingsCTE
                    {
                        MeetingId = m.meetingId
                    }
                )
                .Concat
                (
                    from m in db.Meetings
                    from pm in PriorMeetings
                        .InnerJoin(pm => m.ContinuedMeetingId == pm.MeetingId)
                    select new RelatedMeetingsCTE
                    {
                        MeetingId = m.meetingId
                    }
                );
        });

        var continuedMeetingsCte = db.GetCte<RelatedMeetingsCTE>(ContinuedMeetings =>
        {
            return
                (
                    from m in db.Meetings 
                    where m.MeetingId == meetingId
                    select new RelatedMeetingsCTE
                    {
                        MeetingId = m.ContinuedMeetingId
                    }
                )
                .Concat
                (
                    from m in db.Meetings
                    from cm in ContinuedMeetings
                        .InnerJoin(cm => m.MeetingId == cm.ContinuedMeetingId)
                    select new RelatedMeetingsCTE
                    {
                        MeetingId = m.ContinuedMeetingId
                    }
                );
        });

        var relatedMeetingsCte =
            (
                from pm in priorMeetingsCte
                select new RelatedMeetingsCTE
                {
                    MeetingId = pm.MeetingId
                }
            )
            .Concat
            (
                from cm in continuedMeetingsCte
                select new RelatedMeetingsCTE
                {
                    MeetingId = cm.MeetingId
                }
            )
            .AsCte("RelatedMeetings");

        // Or perhaps just...
        //var relatedMeetingsCte =
        //    priorMeetingsCte
        //    .Concat(continuedMeetingsCte)
        //    .AsCte("RelatedMeetings");

        var result = string.Join(",", (
                from rm in relatedMeetingsCte
                orderby rm.MeetingId
                select rm.MeetingId.ToString()
            ));

        return result;
    }    
}


Looks good. using (var db = context.CreateLinqToDBConnection())
